# Replace current image in JPanel with another one

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, imageicon

I´m writing a program where images are displayed on a JPanel, but I´m having trouble replacing the existing image when I open a new one. Is there a easy way to remove the old image from the ImageIcon and replace with the new one? I thought that something like **mp.remove(pic);** would work here, but it says that it´s not supported for ImageIcon?

```
class MapPanel extends JPanel {

public MapPanel(String filename) {
    if(mp == null) {
    pic = new ImageIcon(filename);
    int w = pic.getIconWidth();
    int h = pic.getIconHeight();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    setLayout(null);
}
    else { int confirm = 
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MapProgram.this, "Unsaved changes, " + 
"do you really want to open a new map?",
            "New map", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (confirm != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                return;     

    // Remove the current image and display the new one choosen 
    // from the JFileChooser.


    }       
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(pic.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: what about just setting the new imageIcon?

Comment: How are you using `pic`? The only thing you've showed us is the creation and assignment `pic = new ImageIcon(filename);` as well as that you get the image dimensions.

Comment: Sorry, some code got lost somehow. See the updated code.

Comment: 1) Why not just display the `ImageIcon` in a `JLabel`? Note also the preferred size of a label will change automatically on change of `ImageIcon`, whereas the preferred size of that panel is only set when constructed. 2) `setLayout(null);` Unnecessary for custom painting. Inadvisable at any other time.

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks for the input. So if i understand everything correctly the new image will automatically replace the old one? My concern was that a new image would be created on top of the old one everytime.

Comment: Consider leaving the `ImageIcon` in place and updating it via, `setImage()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ImageIcon at all? It appears you want to draw an Image in a JPanel, not sure why you are using ImageIcon. Use ImageIO.read() to read the file chosen by the file chooser as an BufferedImage. Set the image to a member variable, then in paintComponent() instead of pic.getImage(), use your member variable.  After a file is chosen and you set your member variable to the new file call repaint().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-

Also, setting preferredSize, min size, and max size may or may not do anything. It all depends on what layout manager the container you put this JPanel in is using.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work for what you want to do but give it a try.

```
g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(filename).getImage(), 0, 0, this);
```

or just pass in an Image there.